# Python: Error occurring in IF/ELIF statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a program I need to write for college and I have an error in my code that I don't know how to fix

```py
#calculate savings and print users total cost
if voucher_quant < 20:
    print("Your total will be £", str(voucher_value*voucher_quant))
    elif voucher_quant => 20 and voucher_quant=<40:
        print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.05)
        elif voucher_quant =>41 and voucher_quant =<70:
            print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.075)
            elif voucher_quant =>71 and voucher_quant =<100:
                print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.1)
```

can anyone help me on how to fix this?

Comment: Use `if` instead of `elif` if you are indenting them. Or else, unindent the `elif`s

Comment: All elif should start at the same position as if. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Comment: Don't indent each elif statement. You also need a terminal 'else' statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` has to be at same identation level as its `if` is.

Comparison operators are like `<=` and not `=<`. `=` would be latter

Your print statements do not complete brackets

This code is correct syntactically

```
voucher_quant = 50 # Change as you want
voucher_value = 10 # Change as you want

if voucher_quant < 20:
    print("Your total will be £", str(voucher_value*voucher_quant))

elif voucher_quant >= 20 and voucher_quant<=40:
    print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.05))

elif voucher_quant >= 41 and voucher_quant <= 70:
    print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.075))

elif voucher_quant >= 71 and voucher_quant<=100:
    print("Your total will be £", str((voucher_value*voucher_quant)*0.1))


#Output
#Your total will be £ 37.5
```